# Using javascript to alter noUIslider tags in R Shiny error when performing Math.pow(10,x) when x = 0

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, nouislider

In an earlier SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54556304/customize-labels-to-an-exponential-text-format-on-a-vertical-nouisliderinput-in/54605592?noredirect=1#comment96028185_54605592) I have come to a point where I have a `noUiSliderInput` that gets it's labels updated to a scientific notation format with the help of `javascript`.

**The remaining problem is that the `noUiSliderInput` jumps to 10 when the input is 0 and it therefore should jump to 1. (10^0 is 1, not 10). I suspect a problem with Math.pow(10,x) is the cause but I am not sure**

**UPDATE:**
The initial problem of the slider jumping to the maximum value has been fixed by changing the `javascript` code, which now takes values from `shiny` as input for the min, max and value of the slider. 
I have changed the code of the app here in the question to represent the current situation.

**#END UPDATE#**

*The behavior is simulated here with the use of a second `sliderInput` and `numericInput` boxes that causes all three values needed for the noUiSliderInput to cahange*

In my real `app` the `noUiSliderInput` is linked to a `plot`, and whatever data `column` the user chooses to `plot`. So, whatever data the user chooses to plot will require the `noUiSliderInput` to `update` it's `range`. The `slider` is also linked to a `datatable` with earlier created settings (a datatable of threshold values for some of the columns in the data), and when the user clicks a `datatable` entry, it will `update` the drop down that selects which data is to be plotted (and thus the `noUiSliderInput` `range`), as well as at what height the threshold (`noUiSliderInput` `value`) should be based on the value in the `datatable`.

This fires three changes at once, range (i.e. min & max of `noUiSliderInput`), as well as value of the `noUiSliderInput`.

I managed to get a dummy `app` that simulates this behavior working, except the `value` of the `noUiSliderInput` gets updated wrong by the current `javascript` it seems.

The schematic looks like this roughly
[image]

Where you can see that clicking on the `table` will send a value to the `noUiSliderInput` value, and a parameter name to the parameter `selectInput`, which then gets the data, sends it to the `plot`, and send the min, max: `range` to the `noUiSliderInput`. 
It is build this way because the user can also select parameters (`columns`) from the `selectInput` directly (many of which are not in the table of thresholds)

**App so far:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

js <- function(Min, Max, Start){
  sprintf(paste(
    "var slider = document.getElementById('Histoslider').noUiSlider;",
    "slider.updateOptions({",
    "  start: %s,",
    "  range: {min: %s, max: %s},",
    "  format: wNumb({", 
    "    encoder: function(x){return parseFloat(Math.pow(10,x));}", 
    "  })", 
    "});",
    "var pipsValues = $('.noUi-value');",
    "pipsValues.each(function(){$(this).html('10<sup>'+$(this).attr('data-value')+'</sup>')});",
    sep = "\n"
  ), Start, Min, Max)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           uiOutput('TestSliderOut'), 
           actionButton(inputId = "UpdateSlider", label = 'Update')
    ),
    column(6, 
           sliderInput("slider2", label = NULL, min = -5, max = 20, value= c(1, 5), step = 1),
           numericInput(inputId = 'SlMin', label = 'Min', value = 1, min = -5, max = 20),
           numericInput(inputId = 'SlMax', label = 'Max', value = 5, min = -5, max = 20),
           numericInput(inputId = 'SlVal', label = 'Val', value = 3, min = -5, max = 20),
           br(),
           h5('Update counter'),
           verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "updates"),
           h5('slider value'),
           verbatimTextOutput(outputId = 'ouputval')
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues( Counter = 0)

  output$TestSliderOut <- renderUI({
    noUiSliderInput(
      inputId = "Histoslider", label = "Slider vertical:",
      min = -2, max = 4, step = 0.01,
      value = 0, margin = 100, 
      pips = list(mode="range", density=2),
      orientation = "vertical", 
      width = "300px", height = "300px",   direction = "rtl", 
      behaviour = "tap"
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$slider2, {
    ## simulates the change of multipe parameters of the slider: min, max, value
    newvalue <- (input$slider2[2]-input$slider2[1])/2+input$slider2[1]
    updateNumericInput(session, inputId = 'SlMin', value = input$slider2[1])
    updateNumericInput(session, inputId = 'SlMax', value = input$slider2[2])
    updateNumericInput(session, inputId = 'SlVal', value = newvalue)

  })

  observe({
    updateNoUiSliderInput(session, inputId = 'Histoslider', range = c(input$SlMin, input$SlMax), value = input$SlVal)
    shinyjs::delay(1, {  ## delay the javascript so that it runs after the slider has updated its values
      runjs(js(input$SlMin, input$SlMax, input$SlVal))     })
  })

  output$updates <- renderPrint(values$Counter)


  output$ouputval <- renderPrint(input$Histoslider)

  observeEvent(input$SlMin, { values$nouiMin <- input$SlMin })
  observeEvent(input$SlMax, { values$nouiMax <- input$SlMax })
  observeEvent(input$SlVal, { values$nouiVal <- input$SlVal })

  observeEvent(input$Histoslider, {
    print('changing code')
    runjs(js(values$nouiMin, values$nouiMax, values$nouiVal))     ## fires ones on first build of the slider
  }, once = TRUE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm that does look strange. It seems to work by using the `set` method (set the value of the slider) instead of updating the `start` option:

```
js <- function(Min, Max, Start){
  sprintf(paste(
    "var slider = document.getElementById('Histoslider').noUiSlider;",
    "slider.updateOptions({",
    "  range: {min: %s, max: %s},",
    "  format: wNumb({", 
    "    decimals: 2,",
    "    encoder: function(x){return parseFloat(Math.pow(10,x));}", 
    "  })", 
    "});",
    "slider.set(%s);",
    "var pipsValues = $('.noUi-value');",
    "pipsValues.each(function(){$(this).html('10<sup>'+$(this).attr('data-value')+'</sup>')});",
    sep = "\n"
  ), Min, Max, Start)
}
```

Note that the `updateNoUiSliderInput` in your code is useless, because the slider is updated by the JS code. So replace

```
  observe({
    updateNoUiSliderInput(session, inputId = 'Histoslider', range = c(input$SlMin, input$SlMax), value = input$SlVal)
    shinyjs::delay(1, {  ## delay the javascript so that it runs after the slider has updated its values
      runjs(js(input$SlMin, input$SlMax, input$SlVal))     })
  })
```

with

```
  observeEvent(list(input$SlMin, input$SlMax, input$SlVal), {
      runjs(js(input$SlMin, input$SlMax, input$SlVal))     
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
```

Comment: Ah yes you seem to be right. In all my changing between JavaScript's I didn't realize the double update, and believe it or not, I never knew you could combine observevent with a list like that.

Comment: It works really well now. One last detail though, how to get the slider value box to be rounded? I tried to add .toFixed(2) but probably in the wrong place as it did have no effect

Comment: @Mark Between the line `"  format: wNumb({",` and the line `"    encoder: function(x){return parseFloat(Math.pow(10,x));}",`, add the line `"    decimals: 2,",` (note the comma after `2`).

Comment: You're a star! I hope you read the chat messages I send on the previous question by the way. Appreciate the help you keep providing. Learning a bit more about javascript every day