# How can I replace the value with the name in sliderInput in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

How can I replace the value with the name in `sliderInput ()` in shiny?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
          min = 1, max = 10, value = 10),
 plotOutput("distPlot")
)
```

I would like to have 1 as (the least) and 10 as (the most) on the sliderInput.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415471/sliderinput-max-min-text-labels